# <p:dataTable filteredValue> is called in spite of rendered=false

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am wondering about the following behaviour of `<p:dataTable filteredValue>`. Hopefully you can explain it and tell me how to avoid it.

The backing bean method is called even though the corresponding component is not rendered.

```
<p:panel rendered="#{false}">
    <p:dataTable ... filteredValue="#{backingBean.filteredRowModels}">
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
```

Do you know how avoid calling the backing bean method if it is not rendered?

Comment: Just put a debug breakpoint and inspect the call stack as usual in order to figure out why the line of code is called.

Comment: The init Method is called during DataBaseTable.getFilteredValue. As mentioned before, the corresponding DataTable is not rendered. Does JSF process Component even thou there are not rendered?

Comment: Excellent. I've fixed your question. The original question was way too blurred. I'd say this is in the end just a bug/oversight in PrimeFaces. Report issue and in the meanwhile patch the renderer.

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces are you using? Filtering was overhauled in PF 10, did you try with that version?

Comment: We are using Primefaces 8.0

Comment: As a workaround, I replaced the rendered attribute with a c:if tag to prevent Primefaces from initialising the bean.

Comment: Can you please try with 10 to see if an issue needs to be reported?